# There is no rsync command in Microsoft/dotnet: latest image

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working with gitlab-ci and docker, and I want to automate deployment.

I have a problem: I cannot use rsync command with official .NET image.

If Microsoft decided to not provide this command, I think it is because I am doing my deployment by the wrong way.

What is the official way to deploy and ASP.net core MVC web application in production with gitlab-ci and docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, but I've not yet deployed, I'm just testing at the moment directly from the Docker container.

It looks like the version of Linux is Debian Stretch 9.
You can fix missing packages by doing [fix-unable-to-locate-package-error-in-debian-9](https://www.tecmint.com/fix-unable-to-locate-package-error-in-debian-9/)

This is how I've done it:

```
echo "deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian  stretch main" >> /etc/aptsources.list
apt-get update
apt-get install -y rsync
rsync --version
```

There may be a better solution, but this does get rsync and any other packages you want installed.

---

I've tested it in Gitlab and this works for me:

```
deploy-test:
  stage: deploy-dotnet

  image: microsoft/dotnet

script:
  - echo "deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian  stretch main" >> /etc/aptsources.list
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -y rsync
```